# Empty table after seeding in laravel8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I just started working with `Laravel` and i'm trying to seed my DB. I have a `many to many` relationship between the `users` and `shops` table.

[image]

When i'm running `php artisan DB:seed` the seeder for `shops` isn't running. And if i run `php artisan db:seed --class=ShopsTableSeeder` i'm getting an Error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`

The factory file :

```js
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Models\Shop;

$factory->define(Shop::class, function () {
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');

    return [
        'title' => $faker->text($maxNbChars = 20),
        'description' => $faker->text(250),
        ...
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'active_until' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('+0 days', '+2 years'),
    ];
});
```

And the seeding file :

```js
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Shop;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ShopsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        factory(Shop::class, 10)->create();

        foreach (Shop::all() as $shop){
            $users = User::inRandomOrder()->take(rand(1,3))->pluck('id');
            $shop->users()->attach($users);
        }
    }
}
```

how can i set the column user_id in the factory to connect a shop to user ?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The column user_id in your shops table **cannot** be null and your factory doesn't set it.

Comment: `$shop->users()->attach($users);` this line shouldn't do that ?

Comment: `factory(...)->create()`

Comment: I didn't understand your answer

Comment: Your shop factory does not return a user_id column.

Comment: How can i connect it to a user_id from the User Table ?

Comment: I suppose you could add the key `'user_id' =>  User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id` to the shop factory definition.